# Passing a Perl variable to Javascript function called by HTML

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I have this code

Perl

```
my $var1 = to_json \@an_array1;
my $var2 = to_json \@an_array2;
```

HTML

```
<select id="example" title="example" onchange="doThis(<% $var1, $var2 %>)">
```

JavaScript

```
function doThis(var1, var2){
    alert(var1);
    alert(var2);
};
```

However it is alerting that var1 and var2 are undefined, so the parameter is not being passed. (n.b. it is definetly defined in the Perl, done a Dumper!).

Can anyone help on the correct way to pass a Perl variable into JavaScript? I have searched the website but I cannot find anything that helps me with what I'm asking.

Thanks

Comment: You need to look at what the page looks like when it makes it out to the browser.

Comment: Perl is a server-side language, while JavaScript is a client-side language. That means that your Perl has already been processed before JavaScript ever gets processed. Any variables you declared in Perl are gone.

Comment: What @Pointy means is - load the page in your browser and check the source - how does `onChange="doThis()"> look exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're templating engine is, but this is suspect to me,

```
<select id="example" title="example" onchange="doThis(<% $var1, $var2 %>)">
```

vs

```
<select id="example" title="example" onchange='doThis("<% $var1 %>", "<% $var2 %>")'>
```

Notice the comma and quotes Also, make sure the `<% %>` is HTML Escaping the contents. Now whether or not this is safe is an entirely different question. You're going to want to be sure in perl that `$var1` and `$var2` do not have `"` nor do they end in a terminal `\`. It's going to get ugly.

Comment: I don't know the (unspecified) template language used here, but won't that fail if it the JSON contains quotes? Looks like an injection error.